# Screen brightness stuck at maximum

Tags: screen, brightness

My Samsung laptop (series 7 Chronos, Radeon graphics, Core i5) came originally with Windows 8. When upgraded to Windows 10 the display brightness became stuck at maximum. The function keys also became unresponsive. But that is a different story.

After a lot of complaining and dely, Samsung provided a stand alone software that adjusted the brightness. It was not integrated into Windows 10. I got tired of the whole things and ditched Windows 10 and started using Ubuntu.
Now I am still stuck with this dazzling bright screen which does not respond to brightness controls provided by Ubuntu.

I noticed that many people have had the same problem with other types of computers. I have tried some of them, but so far to no avail. Being new to Ubuntu I don't want to try anything too drastic in case I mess up my Ubuntu set up which is working very well at the moment.

I would be grateful for any suggestions that can fix the problem (and save my eyesight!)

Many thaks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a bug report on launch pad describing the same problem and some solutions: [Samsung 7 screen brightness](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1485246)

Basically ACPI is implemented improperly on your motherboard with Intel CPU and Radeon graphics. The solution is to add the parameters `acpi_osi=linux` and `acpi_backlight=video` to your kernel command lines in Grub. You can google how to modify grub kernel parameters and ask any questions you have on updating grub.

Comment: A solution offered at: http://lordamit.github.io/Brightness/   has partially worked for me. I say partially because the python app,  when executed, disables the terminal window and I have to open a new one.  But it is better than nothing. I will try the suggestion by WinEunuuchs2Unix as soon as I know how to modify grub kernel parameters.

Comment: It's described in AskUbuntu:  [how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

Comment: Success! I added the parameters to the kernel command line in Grub as suggested above and rebooted. Brightness control was back. Thank you WinEunuuchs2Unix, you saved my laptop (and eyesight!)

Comment: I understand the eyesight point. I had same experience in 2014 when I started Ubuntu with my old Toshiba laptop. Could you upvote answer back to zero and mark as solved please. Thanks