# How do I set default screen brightness?

Tags: display, laptop, brightness, system-settings, backlight

Before you say this is a duplicate, I've already looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart) and that did not solve my problem.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and ever since the beginning it has maximum brightness by default, which I want down to like 60-80% or so. I tried `xbacklight -set 50`, and that doesn't do anything. I also found out I have a `/sys/class/backlight` directory with folder `dell_backlight` that has max brightness 15 and `intel_backlight` that has max brightness 120000.

The Fn+ brightness hotkeys (F11/F12) of the laptop seem to work, it changes the brightness value in `dell_backlight/brightness`, but it doesn't actually change the brightness of the screen.

That is, the keys themselves work in the sense that they do something, but somehow they don't have the desired effect.
If I manually alter the value in `intel_backlight/brightness`, that doesn't change the brightness of the screen either.

I don't really care so much if the brightness keys work, but most importantly I want to set my default so when I start up it's comfortable and not blindingly bright.

EDIT: the laptop is a dell xps 15 7590

Comment: You are missing a key bit of information: make and model of your machine. Please edit it into the question. Mind also that some machines also have settings in BIOS for this.

Comment: This post might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/818167/screen-brightness-stuck-at-maximum

Comment: @elmclose I tried the suggested answer, but all it does is replace the `/sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight' with '/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0'. The Fn+brightness hotkeys now change the value in 'acpi_video0/brightness' without affecting the actual screen brightness.

Comment: Other people seem to have had similar issues with their Dell laptops. MS Windows users have come up with odd ways of overcoming it. Check out this link: https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-15-L521X-Unable-to-Adjust-Screen-Brightness/td-p/6095414