# Cannot change sceen brightness / Intel + Nvidia GPUs / Ubuntu 18.04 + 20.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, brightness

The problem, function key does not change the brightness of my screen, the slider moves but nothing changes.

The brigthness being always at max, I use this as a work around

`xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness .5`

My setup

Lenovo Legion

CPU: Intel I5 9300H

GPU: TU116M Nvidia GeForce GTX1660 Ti + Intel UHD Graphics 660

The things I have tried:

- Changing Nvidia Prime settings, (economics, on-demand, performance)
- Switching between Intel and Nvidia GPU with nvidia-settinga
- Changing Grub values GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=

Many post says many different things about what to put in those values, since I do not understand, maybe I did not put the right values in it

- Changing drivers in "Additional drivers" section of settings
- Updating drivers for Nvidia
- Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04
- Adding this section to /usr/share/X11/x.conf.d/10-nvidia.org
- settings > power > screen brightness slider, it slides but brightness doesn't change

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "nvidia"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName "<your graphic card as it named in your system>"
    Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Maybe I did not find the right name to fill for Boardname,Ubuntu would not boot until I removed those lines

I'm looking for new things to try, things I could have done wrong in the previous step, a fix, anything that could prevent my eyes from burning looking at my screen

Comment: This post might help :https://askubuntu.com/questions/818167/screen-brightness-stuck-at-maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find the solution thanks to elmclose comment

I had to change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` in `/etc/default/grub`

I originaly  added `acpi_osi=linux` and `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the line

Changing from `acpi_backlight=vendor` to `acpi_backlight=video` worked for me

Save the file, run `sudo update-grub`, reboot, it should work just fine now